# How do i add another function in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, axios

How do i add multiple get posts in Vue.js.

I already have one post that I'm getting fine but I'm not sure how to add multiple post functions.

This is what i have so fare.

```
<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
        return {
            searchQuery: null,
            info: null,
            loading: true,
            errored: false
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        axios.post('https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=vue')
        .then(response => {
            this.info = response.data
            console.log(this.info)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            this.errored = true
        })
        .finally(() => this.loading = false)
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at `Promise.all()` (link to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)). You could do something like:

```js
Promise.all([
  axios.post('https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=vue'),
  axios.post('https://example.com/...')
]).then(responses => {
  console.log(responses);
  // will output an array with responses[0] equals to the data of the first call and responses[1] equals to the data of the second call
})
// Add your catch and finally clauses here...
```

The benefits of this approach is that **your calls are made in parallel** but the then clause will only be reached when they both ended.

Comment: The benefit depends on the usecase....if the second request has to be made from the first then we can't go for concurrent calls :) else this one is the best...I agree

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the calls one after the other then
you can just nest the second axios call inside the first one.
In this way you can keep nesting to multiple levels

```
axios.post('https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=vue').then(response => {
   this.arrayOne = response.data
   axios.post('https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=vue').then(
       response => this.arrayTwo = response.data
     );
  });
```

OR

You can try using async/await
Below is an example where I have used the response of first request to make the second request.

```
async mounted()  {
  try {
    const response1 = await axios.get('/user/12345');
    this.arrayOne = response1.data;
    const response2 = await axios.get(`/user/12345/${this.arrayOne.name}/permissions`);
    this.arrayTwo = response2.data;
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```